# reducing size of the section in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i am very much new to iphone development ,I wanted to reduce the size of a  section in the  grouped table view i.e reducing the width of the section . how can it be implemented
thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried reducing the width of the whole tableview?

Comment: @Nick Weaver : No actually i did not know that also.i want to do it for  both section and table view

Comment: You can set the size of the whole tableView with `myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);`. You have to adjust the values for CGRectMake. The section should shrink accordingly. Please try that and tell us if that suits your needs.

Comment: @Nick Weave:ya i will check out n tell you..

Comment: @Nick Weave: hey i want to change the width of a row within the table view not the size of table view..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return kHeightForHeaderInSection;
}   


 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // wrapperView - by default has the width of the table, you can change the height
        // with the heightForHeaderInSection method
        UIView *aView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];

        // your real section view: a label, a uiview, whatever
        CGRect myFrame; // create your own frame
        myFrame.origin = CGPointMake(10, 0);
        myFrame.size = CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width-10,kHeightForHeaderInSection); 
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame] autorelease];
        label.text = @"myText"
        [aView addSubview:label];

        return aView;
    }
```

Comment: in your tableView delegate you need to implement the above method. The viewForHeaderInSection return a view (let's call myView) with a height equal to the value returned by heightForHeaderInSection and width equal to the tableView width. At this point you can just create and add your target view (ie a label) with your own defined frame and add it to myView. Another approach would be to subclass UILabel methods: - textRectForBounds: limitedToNumberOfLines: and -drawTextInRect:.

Answer (score 0):

Hi add this UITableviewdelegate method

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its a very simple soln   ...

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
IBOutlet UITableview *myTableview;
```

just right click on "UITableViewDelegate" and "UITableViewDataSource"

n implement all the delegates....u will find all types of adjustment over there....weather u want to change or adjust height or width of section or row ...or how many section or how many rows in a section do u want....
its simple n called automatically.... regards